# Plotting incorrectly

Tags: plotting

When I write:

```
Plot[E^x-3x, {x, -10, 10}]
```

I have this as an output:
[image]

However, the graph should look like this:
[image]

Why is there this discrepancy?

Comment: you have different [PlotRange](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the option [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html):

```
Plot[E^x - 3 x, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-5, 20}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Plot[E^x - 3 x, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {All, {-5, 20}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful :)

Comment: @alyssa, you are welcome. And welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 0):

or try `AspectRatio`

```
 Plot[E^x - 3 x, {x, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-5, 10}}]
```